# C++ / Qt: track filesystem changes

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

I'm currently trying to implement a c++ program which monitors a folder on the filesystem. On initalizing the application, it scans the Directory and saves some meta information about it.

when something is chenged while the program is active, i can read changes to the folder (for examlpe changing the name of a folder or a file). But i can't track changes to the Directory while the program isn't running. Upon startup i would get

```
Removed folder X
Added folder Y
```

instead of

```
Renamed folder X to Y
```

is it possible to identify a directory in another way than it's path/name? 
if yes, how would i gather that information in C++ / Qt ?

Comment: Can you place a hidden file in the monitored folders for identification purpose?

Comment: That wouldn't help me, since it could not identify the directory when the name changes

Comment: I was thinking this combined with QFileSystemWatcher. Although if your application was not running you would have to scan at startup to find out if your tagged folders have moved.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, you could just use the class QFileSystemWatcher which the Qt docs states: -

> The QFileSystemWatcher class provides an interface for monitoring
>   files and directories for modifications

If you want the program to run all the time, then you may want to look at creating a service (in Windows) or daemon (Linux / OSX).

Comment: but does that include changes to the FS while the application isn't running?

Comment: Edited before your comment was added. Does that answer it for you?

Comment: The only possible way for you to get the file system changes since your application last started is to maintain a cache of the entire filesystem and then tranverse the entire file system on startup, and check each file.

If this sounds expensive to you, that is because it is, unfortunately, almost all fileindexers in linux do this when they want to check for files they haven't been notified about.

Comment: Well, partly. I don't really like the option to build a Service for that purpose. Isn't there any other way of identifying an directory? like an id the FS itself uses to identify it?

Comment: What platform are you writing for?

Comment: Windows at the moment, other platforms may come. but mainly windows

Comment: As @VisheshHanda said, the only way is to maintain a copy and compare. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to write a service?

Comment: well...i just started to write the service. I just never did that before, so I have basically no idea how to do it (but i already found the examples ad m$.com, will work through that...).

Comment: No problem, though do note that QFileSystemWatcher is certainly the way to go here, rather than trying to do it yourself.

Comment: yea, i'm already using that to watch changes while the main application is running

Answer (score 0):

This is filesystem-specific, but generally yes this is possible. FAT is the main exception, I think. But you won't find code for this in the C++ Standard Library or Qt. It's just too unusual, so you'll need OS-specific code if not filesystem-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Like TheDarkNight said, you need to use QFileSystemWatcher to avoid portability and so other problem.
But if you want to continue your approach:
In GNU/Linux land, you can check this with inode struct of directory (take care of symbolic link issue). 
inode struct have an index for example you can get it on shell with:

```
ls -id /path/to/your/folder
```

There is an API to access inode. You can google inode struct linux for it.

In Windows garden, you can get file id when accessing handle in the struct [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **nFileIndexHigh**
>       The high-order part of a unique identifier that is associated with a file. 
>       For more information, see nFileIndexLow.
>       **nFileIndexLow**
>       The low-order part of a unique identifier that is associated with a file.